# Why does this inequality have a tight triangular form?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I am having trouble applying the definition of a tight triangular inequality in the context of the symmetric and the graphical traveling salesman polytope.

The definition of a tight triangular inequality is as follows

\begin{align*} & \Delta _{f}\left( u\right) =\{ \left( v,w\right) \in E:v\neq u,w\neq u, &f_{vw}=f_{uv}+f_{uw} \} \end{align*} where $f_{xy}$ corresponds to the weight of edge $(x,y)$ in a weighted graph.

> **Definition:** An inequality $fx\ge f_o$ defined on $R^{\mathbb{E}}$(x $\in R^{\mathbb{E}}$) is said to be tight
>   triangular or in tight triangular form if the following conditions are
>   satisfied:
>
> - The coefficients $f_e$ satisfy the triangular inequality, i.e. $f_{uv}\le f_{uw}+f_{wv}$ for each triplet $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ of distinct nodes of $V.$
> - $ \Delta _{f}\left( u\right) \neq \emptyset$   for all u $\in V$

I know that the inquality $ x\left( \delta \left( \left\{ u,v\right\} \right) \right) \geq2$ has a **tight triangular form** , however I can not understand how the definition applies on this inequality.

The required definitions to understand the inequality are:

\begin{align*} & x\left( F\right) =\sum _{e\in F}x_{e}\end{align*}

\begin{align*} & \delta(S) = \left\{ e=\left( i,j\right) :\left| S\cap \left\{ i,j\right\} \right| =1\right\}&  \end{align*}

My question is for this inequality, what is $f$ exactly? What exactly should satisfy the triangle inequality (and hence the definition)? Should I check if $x$ satisfies the triangle inequality? But $x$ is just a solution(a eulerian tour in this case), the inequality should be tight triangular independent of the $x$.

The tight triangular inequality was first defined in:

- The Graphical Relaxation: A New Framework for the Symmetric Traveling Salesman Polytope (only abstract link [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220588743_The_Graphical_Relaxation_A_New_Framework_for_the_Symmetric_Traveling_Salesman_Polytope)) by Naddef & Rinaldi (1993)

I am reading however the book

- The Traveling Salesman Problem and Its Variations by Gutin & Punnen (2007)

Comment: In order that your text is more understandable by the layman, you should define properly $f_{uv}$ as the weight of edge $(u,v)$ in a weighted graph.

Comment: yeah. your right. I just edited the question